# Yarn start with NX - Error on react-app-rewired:

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I am trying to serve my application, using `yarn start` command.

But I have this error I can't understand :

```
yarn run v1.22.4
warning package.json: "dependencies" has dependency "react-scripts" with range "3.2.0" that collides with a dependency in "devDependencies" of the same name with version "^3.4.1"
$ nx serve

> nx run phoenix:serve
FOLDER\front\node_modules\.bin\react-app-rewired:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1172:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1277:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1105:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I upgraded NodeJS to the last version. And I have last version of Yarn.

I am really lost here and dunno what to do ?

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, don't use the react-app-rewired script in the node_modules/.bin directory, but instead use the one in the react-app-rewired/bin directory.

In `workspace.json`

From: `"command": "node ../../node_modules/.bin/react-app-rewired start",`

To: `"command": "node ../../node_modules/react-app-rewired/bin/index.js start",`